# Rearranging terms in infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I cannot understand the following rearranging of series sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i} \frac{c_i}{n+a_i}  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{a_i<n}c_i]$$

where $$a_i$$ are N distinct positive integers and $$c_i$$ also N distinct positive integers

This comes from the following correction to a problem on hackerrank (i do not understand the part highlighted in red):

[problem editorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYXSk.png)

Any insights on how this works?

Comment: You should try to make your Question reasonably self-contained.  It is fine to link to another site as motivation for a problem, but it is unfair to Readers to ask them to pursue links to find the problem statement itself.  The body of the Question should give a full statement of the problem you want help with, preferably using mathematical expressions as appropriate, but if necessary words can be used with "ASCII math" until a willing Reader takes up the conversion to $\LaTeX$.

Comment: ok sorry about this i put it into Latex

Comment: @user3880722 Thanks especially for giving proper definitions for $a_i$ and $c_i$, which were absent from the screenshot and quite important for this step (at least the fact that $a_i$ are positive integers is significant).  Your thoughtful efforts to make the question self-contained are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a *formal* way to arrive at that result would be
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum^k_{i=1}\frac{c_i}{n+a_i}=\sum^k_{i=1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_i}{n+a_i}=\sum^k_{i=1}\sum_{n>a_i}^{\infty} \frac{c_i}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum^k_{a_i<n}\frac{c_i}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^k_{a_i<n}c_i,$$ where we changed the order of summation twice, and transformed the summation index from $n+a_i$ to $n$ in the inner sums, once. But that would be problematic, because those inner sums diverge, much like the harmonic series. The source you quoted mentioned that, but added somewhat vaguely that it's OK in this case. It is, but the reason for that is the equation (the fact is mentioned there) $$\sum^k_{i=1}c_i=0,$$ the necessary and sufficient condition for the entire series to converge. Then, our last sum has only finitely many summands, because $\sum^k_{a_i<n}c_i=0$ for $n>\max_i a_i.$
A somewhat more rigorous approach will give more insight, too. Let's assume the $a_i$ are increasing. We have $c_k=-\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}c_i,$ so our initial sum becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum^k_{i=1}c_i\left(\frac{1}{n+a_i}-\frac{1}{n+a_k}\right)=\sum^k_{i=1} c_i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+a_i}-\frac{1}{n+a_k}\right).$$ Here, everything is OK, because the double sum is absolutely convergent. Now, the inner sums on the RHS are of telescoping type, only finitely many terms remain, the others cancel out:
$$\sum^k_{i=1} c_i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+a_i}-\frac{1}{n+a_k}\right)=\sum^k_{i=1} c_i\sum_{a_i<n\le a_k}\frac{1}{n}.$$ In this finite sum, we can change the order of summation once again, to arrive at the result on the rightmost side, above.

Comment: great answer, why is ∑i=1kci=0, the the necessary and sufficient condition for the entire series to converge?

Comment: I showed it's sufficient, and it's also necessary: if there's just one $c_1=1$ and $a_1=0,$ you have the divergent harmonic series.

Comment: not sure how your example proves that the series converge => ∑i=1kci=0

Comment: Because $\sum_i c_i/(n+a_i)=(\sum_ic_i)/n+O(1/n^2),$ and while $\sum_n1/n^2$ converges, $\sum_n1/n$ does not.